# Mocha test html report is not generating for all test files in visual studio code throwing an error as windows can not find the test file

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io, mochawesome

Mocha test html report is not generating for all test files in visual studio code throwing an error as windows can not find the test file.(refer the attached screenshot)

Report is generating for individual test files or if I comment randomly one or two test files out of all test files.Please help me to get this issue fixed
[Mocha Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxs9A.jpg)

I have tried increasing the timeout property, updated the npm version and restarted system and VS Code but still no luck.